# Why is my code not going past the first 2 rows

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessor

I'm trying to **remove self-loops** from **unweighted bipartite graphs**, however my code is only printing the first 2 lines (as a single line), and for every iteration of the loop it prints these 2 lines (as a single line). I'm very new to pandas, and am probably making some looping mistake.

I've tried iterating only over index, and only over row but the end result has been the same.

**Code**:

```
for index,row in dataset.iterrows():
    x = next(dataset.iterrows())
    y=x[1].to_string().split()
    if ((y[0])!=(y[1])):
        outfile.write(x[1].to_string() + "\n")
```

**Input**:

```
% bip unweighted

1 1

1 2

1 3

1 4
...
```

**Actual**:

```
% bip unweighted    1 1

% bip unweighted    1 1 

% bip unweighted    1 1 

...
```

**Expected**:

```
% bip unweighted

1 2

1 3

1 4

...
```

Comment: remove the `next`statement. You are already iterating over rows dont need that. at each iteration the next row is stored in `row` variable. Use that instead of `x`

Comment: @SiddhantTandon Thank you, that worked. the code now runs fine :)